# How to open Excel-document in the separate process?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, excel, com

During running application report is generated by vb .net code and writes results to the Excel file. If it's open another Excel-document, report was generated by vb .net (I use COM) will be closed and this another document too. Here is code of closing:

```
Dim w As Workbook
For Each w In mExcel.Workbooks
    w.Save()
Next
mExcel.Quit()
```

As I know, cause is Excel 2013, it opens documents in the same process. How can I open report from vb .net/c# code in the separate process?

Comment: How is `mExcel` being created?  You should get a stand alone process (unconnected to other open processes) creating `mExcel` with `New`.  If the application needs to open these documents then you can add `w.Close()` to the loop and do a test on `Workbook.Name` to prevent it from closing specific ones.

Comment: Excel is being created using COM-function in vb. net code GetObject(, "Excel.Application")